# codeigniter poll module using hmvc

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I'm trying create a poll module  within codeigniter using hmvc 
I'm trying to return the count as percentages  against the amount of user_id's  that have voted into the candidate_id 
I'm using a so called perfectcontroller and perfectmodel

where I can return the count on the number of rows each candidate has a user_id 
but I have seven candidate_id's so getting the percentages is a little tricky
 but its also tricky trying to get the count to match up against the id its counting
I do not know if this is the right way to go about it or if I should be doing it another way any suggestions  would help 
thanks

```
<?php
function get_result(){
    $query = $this->get_where_custom('candidate_id',$candidate_id);
    $num_rows = $query->num_rows();
    //returns the amount of user votes 
    foreach($query->result() as $row){
        $candidate_id = $row->candidate_id;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter if you have 7 or 77 candidates. Votes are counting. So if you have only one vote in DB, it means 100% for one candidate and 0% for rest of them. I don't know what do you consider by perfectcontroller and perfectmodel. But your table could be like

```
election_id | voter_id | candidate_id
```

your query would be like

```
$this->db->query("SELECT `e`.`candidate_id`, COUNT(1) AS `total`, COUNT(1) / `t`.`cnt` * 100 AS `percentage` FROM `elections` `e` CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS `cnt` FROM `elections`) `t` GROUP BY `e`.`candidate_id`;");
```

Comment: i have my table set up as follows      
 id | user_id | candidate_id 

the perfectcontroller and perfect model is just an ready made controller and model that has all the functions ready made from the CI user guide very handy for module making pretty useful so far i managed to get it  but the long way around by the looks of it to what you showed me

Comment: Was this result you were expecting?

Comment: candidate of 1 has 44.444444444444 %of the vote
candidate of 2 has 55.555555555556 %of the vote

its certainly a start i will have to figure out how to get it to the view and pass the relavant candidate id's across
after i number format it